# Proper way to fetch data from frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, rest, next.js

I am new to NextJS but after some days trying to connect the frontend to the backend I don't realize the proper way. My first attempt was to create a Restful API to perform CRUD operations from the frontend. But, after finding some authentication issues I wasn't able to figure out, and after watch [this guy from Vercel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2o5m1ovfl3c) using NextJS loading feature with `getServerSideProps` function I don't know what to do.

According to the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#getserversideprops-or-api-routes), it's not recommended to use the `getServerSideProps` to fetch data from the API directly.

But [I have also read](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#fetching-data-on-the-client-side) that is not that wrong to fetch data from the API from a dashboard since this does not require any SEO performance.

What I need to understand is, what is the proper way to fetch data from the database? Is this what is not recommended by NextJS?

```
import { getUsers } from '@/services/user-service';

export default function UserDashboard({ users }) {
    const { status } = useSession();

    if (status !== 'authenticated') {
        return <LoadingSpinner />
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {users.map(user => (
                <li key={user._id}>{user.name}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const users = await getUsers();

    return {
        props: {
            users: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)),
        },
    };
}
```

So, tecnically in this approach I don't use the API but the service itself. If this is not the way to connect from, which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with two different concepts here, and both have their valid use cases:

- `getServerSideProps` is used for **server-side rendering**. So if you deliver a page, it will be pre-rendered on the server, delivered to the frontend, hydrated there. The data you fetch in `getServerSideProps` is available in the pre-rendering process on the server. It is useful for rendering data that can be fetched once on page load.
- Using `fetch` in a React component would usually be used for **client-side rendering**. It is executed at runtime in the browser and allows you to fetch data **after** a page has been delivered by the server. It is useful for fetching data that depends on a user interaction or updates frequently without requiring a page reload.

I generally default to server-side rendering unless there is a good reason not to.